# \caption outside float. Algorithms

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

I'm sorry if this is repeated but I'm not able to find my answer.
I am using the following code. But I receive the error:

`! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.`

```
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State $a\gets b$
\State $b\gets r$
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The line `end{algorithmic}` should be `\end{algorithmic}`. With that fix your error disappears for me.

Answer (score 3):

Your code uses nothing involving the [`algorithm2e` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) and the use of the packages conflict with one another. Instead add the [`algorithm` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) to your preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The gcd of $a$ and $b$}
      \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \While{$r \neq 0$}\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is $0$}
        \State $a \gets b$
        \State $b \gets r$
        \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is $b$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Werner. But now I get:  LaTeX Error: Command \algorithm already defined. These are the packages in my article:
\documentclass[twoside,leqno,twocolumn]{article}  

\usepackage{ltexpprt}

\usepackage{url} 

\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

Comment: @Elnaz: Where can one find `ltexpprt`? Based on [this old post](http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/how-do-i-install-ltexpprt-into-a-miktex-environ/1936118) it seems deprecated. I'm guessing it loads some algorithm package/defines the `algorithm` environment.

Comment: I downloaded it from http://www.siam.org/proceedings/macros/soda2e.all 
It's a conference template.

Comment: @Elnaz: Use `\usepackage{ltexpprt} \let\algorithm\relax \usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}`.

Comment: It still gives me this error:
! LaTeX Error: Command \algorithm already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

Comment: @Elnaz: I'm unable to replicate the problem, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `algorithm2e` also defines `algorithm` environment, which is defined in the soda file as well.

One solution is to change `"algorithm"` environment name in `algorithm2e` to `"algorithm2e"` so that the naming conflict is avoided.

like this:

```
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}
```

then wrap your code with:

```
\begin{algorithm2e}
...
\end{algorithm2e}
```